# Hyperplane and associated Half spaces convexity

Tags: convex-analysis

How to prove a [Hyperplane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HsiC.png) and its associated half spaces as convex sets.

I know the convexity condition that if $x,y$ belongs to convex set, then their linear combination should also lie in the set. (Linear combination such that their coefficients are positive and sum to $1$). In this case, it is given $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I 'm confused in taking coefficients. For the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can take any $(t, 1-t)$ such that $t<1$.  I just couldn't start the proof in this case.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $x, y$ in $H$, then $$\sum_i a_i x_i = \sum_i a_i y_i = b$$

Now assume $z= tx+ (1-t)y$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_i a_iz_i &=& \sum_i (ta_i x_i + (1-t)a_iy_i )\\
&=& t \sum_i a_i x_i + (1-t) \sum_i a_i y_i  \\
&=& tb + (1-t)b = b
\end{eqnarray}

A similar calculation  applies to the halfspaces, which are defined by
$$ \{x:\,\sum_i a_i x_i  \ge b\}$$
resp
$$ \{x:\, \sum_i a_i x_i  \le b\}$$

Comment: (i used $a$ instead of $\alpha$ and $b$  instead of $\beta$)